# Find the Missing Key ID or Numbers from a Column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

Need to find the missing numbers which have been deleted or a Column does not have yet.

For example:

i have a table Named Person have Columns [PersonID] [PersonName]

[PersonID] is primary and incremented Number e.g. From 1 to N.

```
PersonID            PersonName
1001                       ABC
1002                       ABC
1003                       XYZ
1004                       MNO
1006                       ABC
1008                       MNO
1009                       ABC
1010                       ABC
1011                       XYZ
1014                       ABC
1015                       ABC
1016                       XYZ
1017                       MNO
```

In the given table ,there are some missing numbers in Column PersonID like

```
1005
1007
1012 
1013
```

Need to find the missing Numbers only.

**Note:** There are more than 20 million records in my table. 
So please suggest a faster method to find the desired numbers.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Create a table containing all the expected numbers then anti join to this table to find the gaps.

Comment: Based on your sample data, shouldn't you be expecting `1005`, not `5`? Also, why does it matter if you don't have concurrent ID's? They don't need to be.

Comment: @Larnu question edited.  Needs to re regenerate the numbers.

Comment: Is `PersonID` your Primary Key? Does it `CLUSTERED`? If the answer to either of these questions is "yes", then regenerating the numbers is a *bad* idea.

Comment: yes it Primary key. nope it is not a clustered key.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all of you who supported and share some points. I have found the way to find the Missing using **ROWNUMBER().**

```
 SELECT
 NOTEXIST  FROM  ( 
 SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PERSONID) NOTEXIST ,PERSONID  FROM  #A )  T
 WHERE NOTEXIST NOT IN  ( SELECT PERSONID  FROM  PERSONID )
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to get *ranges*.  You can do this with `lead()`:

```
select personid + 1, next_personid - 1 as end_range,
       next_personid - personid - 1 as num_missing
from (select t.*,
             lead(personid) over (order by personid) as next_personid
      from t
     ) t
where next_personid <> personid + 1;
```

If you still want the list of ids, you can expand out the ranges, but that depends on the database.

In SQL Server 2008, this is much more performance intensive, but you can do it:

```
select personid + 1, tnext.personid - 1 as end_range,
       text.personid - personid - 1 as num_missing
from t cross apply
     (select top (1) t2.person_id
      from t t2
      where t2.personid > t.person_id
      order by t2.personid asc
     ) tnext
where tnext.personid <> personid + 1;
```

Comment: 'lead' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: This is why knowing what RDBMS you are using is important @Shahbazsaeed38

Comment: i am using MSSQL 2014

Comment: @Shahbazsaeed38 . . . `lead()` is available in both databases that were originally tagged on the question.  It was added into SQL Server in 2012 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: `LEAD` was introduced in SQL Server 2012, @Shahbazsaeed38 . Is your database in compatibility mode 100 or lower?

Comment: compatibility mode is 100

Comment: That's 2008, @Shahbazsaeed38. Any reason you're using an old compatiblity?

Comment: May be you are connecting to a different server(100 compatibility) from SSMS 2012 tool.

Comment: There is no reason so far i know.  things are going smooth so management never planned to upgrade.

Comment: But 2008 is about to completely lose all support @Shahbazsaeed38. That is a reason itself.

Answer (score 0):

Create another table and populate all the numbers between Min and Max ranges of PersonID. Do an anti join (Left/right) to get the list of numbers missing.

```
select * from NewIDTable a
left join OriginalTable b  on a.PersonID=b.PersonID
where b.Personid is null
```

Comment: As i mentioned in the Question there are 20M + records in table it's not a good approach to create the table every time i need to find the difference...table is increasing by every minute.